# System commands like "mkdir" not working in sandbox enabled mode

Tags: macos, cocoa, printing, sandbox

In my cocoa application, I have to install 3rd party print drivers in current system as a part of application. For that I created `installprinter.sh` file and coded system commands for creating folders, copying files and installing printers inside `installprinter.sh`. And I invoked this `installprinter.sh` from [STPrivilegedTask](https://github.com/sveinbjornt/STPrivilegedTask). If I run this application without enabling the sandbox mode, it asked admin privileges and installed all my printers successfully (Works fine).

After that I enabled sandbox mode with allow printing , read/write access for user selected file and programmatically given access for `/Library/Printers using nsopenpanel`.

For testing,

I had given`mkdir /Library/Printers/MyPrint/` inside `installprinter.sh`

If I run this, it doesn't create `MyPrint` folder inside `/Library/Printers/`. Can anyone suggest what have I missed? or sandbox mode won't support to make changes inside /Library folder in any condition?

Comment: Why would you try to distribute a printer driver thru Mac App Store? Or why would you like to have the distribution sandboxed? The App Store Review Guidelines say "2.15 Apps must be self-contained, single application installation bundles, and cannot install code or resources in shared locations". See https://developer.apple.com/appstore/mac/resources/approval/guidelines.html